# Como esconder body de um http post ( onde contem o password ) de pessoas que ficam analisando o tráfego da rede?

Tags: html, get, body

Bom dia feras... Eu tenho um aplicativo windows acessando uma api web na nuvem e pegando alguns dados de segurança do meu sistema... essa api é para trocar informações somente com meu aplicativo windows, por isso eu a protegi com OAuth ( bearer ) e exigi somente aceitar conexões https.

Eu tenho outros computadores no meu local de trabalho com esse aplicativo windows instalado, eu vou em qualquer um deles e instalo um programa de monitoramento de trafego de rede ( fiddler ) e rapidamente consigo ver o body do post ( contendo a minha senha ).

Como evitar que outras pessoas com acesso a esses computadores façam o mesmo e descubram a minha senha da api???

Alguém me ajude por favor , ja estou doido com isso achando que não tem jeito!

Eu acesso a api com o codigo abaixo:

```
HttpClient clienteHttp = new HttpClient();
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
clienteHttp.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://meuUri.com/");

   Dictionary<string, string> tokenDetails = null;
   var login = new Dictionary<string, string>
   {
      {"grant_type", "password"},
      {"username", "meuUserName"},
      {"password", "meuPassWord"},
    };

    string result = "";

    var response = clienteHttp.PostAsync("Token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(login)).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
       tokenDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>> 
          (response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
       if (tokenDetails != null && tokenDetails.Any())
       {
          var tokenNo = tokenDetails.FirstOrDefault().Value;
          clienteHttp.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", 
          tokenNo);
          HttpResponseMessage resp = clienteHttp.GetAsync("api/clientes/"+idCliente).Result;
          resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
          result = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
   MessageBox.Show(respostaApi, "xMarket", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: Geralmente isso é tratado fazendo o uso do https. Se você deseja utilizar https em desenvolvimento, pode gerar um certificado https auto assinado, para utilizar em seu servidor de aplicação.

Comment: @Danizavtz Note que o https já está sendo empregado na api clienteHttp.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://meuUri.com/");

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta... O que eu quero é que somente o meu aplicativo windows fale com essa API web... Vou instalar esse aplicativo em um monte de clientes e quero que fique seguro ( que ninguém lá no cliente com acesso ao computador onde está instalado esse aplicativo windows consiga ver a senha )

Comment: Não sei se ficou bem claro.... mas eu quero instalar esse sistema em varios clientes. se um cliente desses instalar o fiddler na maquina que o sistema se comunica com a api vai ver as senhas, isso que eu quero evitar.